# How do i handle multiple alarm in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am Scheduling Multiple Messages for WhatsApp using AlarmReceiver.java and i am calling AlarmReceiver like this:

```
                    ScheduleMessage scheduleMessage = new ScheduleMessage();
                    scheduleMessage.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                    scheduleMessage.setMessage(main_mes);
                    scheduleMessage.setEnabled(true);
                    new BackTaskNotification(scheduleMessage).execute();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(scheduleMessageActivity, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id",scheduleMessage.getId());
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(scheduleMessageActivity, scheduleMessage.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) scheduleMessageActivity.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    if (alarmManager != null) {

                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,mYear);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,mMonth);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,mDay);
                        Toast.makeText(scheduleMessageActivity, "The message is being schedule for "+ hour +":"+min, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    }
                    scheduleMessageActivity.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(scheduleMessageActivity, "Enter details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

The Problem i am getting is in AlarmReceiver.java, I cannot differentiate which Alarm should be used to send the message to which phone number. The Code for AlarmReceiver.java:

```
public  class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    String phone;
    String message;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        String id = intent1.getStringExtra("id");

        db = DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(context);
        getScheduledMessages(Integer.parseInt(id));


        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if (!phone.equals("")) {
            try {
                String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phone + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
                i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", "== =  = = =" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void getScheduledMessages(final int id){

        disposables.add(db.userDao().getScheduledMessage(id)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<ScheduleMessage>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<ScheduleMessage> scheduleMessages) throws Exception {
                        ArrayList<ScheduleMessage> items = new ArrayList<>(scheduleMessages);

                        Log.e("qqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqq"+items.size()+"---"+id);
                        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

                            final ScheduleMessage scheduleMessage = items.get(i);
                            phone = scheduleMessage.getPhoneNumber();
                            Log.e("qqqqqqqqqqqq","qqqqqqqqqqqq"+phone);
                            message = scheduleMessage.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    }
                }));
    }
}
```

I just need a unique id in Alarm Receiver class through which i can fetch the message and mobile number from database and perform my action. Although i have tried it through intent but it is not the proper way and it not working.

Hope i get the help soon thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should using intent pass to onReceive callback instead of get it from new Intent

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        String id = intent1.getStringExtra("id");
```

```
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: But sir i am calling AlarmReiver multiple times with always a new id so if the previous task is not finished and i called AlarmReceiver Again it will override the id

Comment: I know, you already setup intent.putExtra("id",scheduleMessage.getId()); but inside receiver you your way to get id not correctly